# While/Read/Do/Done Loop Cutting Out Halfway Through Text File

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a bash script where I run a `while/read/do/done` loop that is fed off of a text file with 200+ values in it. I have this bash script set on my cron to run three times per morning. I am running into an issue where the while read loop is not finishing reading line-by-line the text file. I have included all relevant code below. I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop.

What could be causing this?

**Bash Script Code:**

```
while read point; do

  echo "${point}"

done < /home/admin/site_list
```

**site_list File (Sample):**

```
KBOS
KLWM
KOWD
KPYM
```

**crontab job:**

```
07 6 * * * time /home/admin/all.sh > /home/admin/logs/all1.log1 2>&1
08 10 * * * time /home/admin/all.sh > /home/admin/logs/all1.log2 2>&1 
14 13 * * * time /home/admin/all.sh > /home/admin/logs/all1.log3 2>&1
```

Comment: Does a hex viewer show any special characters in the file? Otherwise that shell code will skip the last line if it lacks an ultimate newline, but that's shell for you.

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765) especially the part about stdin of commands within the loop.

Comment: And also [Understand "IFS= read -r line"?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184)

Comment: Here, if you're using `ssh` without `-n` within the loop, see [Why the behavior of while loop and for loop is different?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/56876)

Comment: Hi @thrig, thanks for responding. The file does have `LF`s at the end of each line.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thank you for linking me to that article. Unfortunately, using text is what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should redirect stderr of `time /home/admin/all.sh` into the log file or some other file. My guess is that you're missing the error message. `crond` typically emails any stdout or stderr output to the owner of the cron job. I can't tell from your info what user ID that is: might be root. Check the email on that machine for emails from `crond` to see what that says.